# Unsure how to use .help() in Swift 5 to achieve a Tooltip

Tags: ios, swiftui, swift5

I've tried the following:

```
 Text("Test Word")
    .help(Text("Hello, this is a tooltip")
```

And many other iterations, but I seem to have no clue on how to work it, and Google isn't helping me at all.

Wondering if this is even possible?

Appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: use `.help("Hello, this is a tooltip")` without the `Text()`... and it only shows a tooltip on macOS!

Comment: This doesn't work on iOS. Or at least for me

Comment: yes exactly, that's why i wrote "only on macOS" ;)

Comment: There is no such *concept* as tooltip for iOS, that is why you did not get what you would expected (from desktop experience).